# TypeScript JavaScript + JSDoc @template type union confusion

Tags: typescript

I have a JavaScript JSDoc annotated function type-checked using TypeScript.

It takes an object of one of the types of a given type union (`Message`). The union types have some optional fields (`optionalNumber` for `AMessage`, `optionalString` for `BMessage`).

The function returns an object of the same type. I use `@template` to annotate that. Additionally, the optional fields are defined in the result. I use `Required` to annotate that:

```js
/** @typedef {{ type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; }} AMessage */
/** @typedef {{ type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; }} BMessage */
/** @typedef {AMessage | BMessage} Message */

/**
 * @template {Message} T
 * @param {T} message
 * @returns {Promise<Required<T>>}
 */
async function exchangeMessage(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* … */ });
}

// `message` = `Required<{ type: "a"; }>` here (Intellisense on hover)
const message = await exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' });

// TODO: Why is this not accessible?
message.optionalNumber;

export {};
```

However, when accessing the result, I only see the fields of the type that are marked as required in the type union and thus are guaranteed to be present in the function argument object.

I do not see the fields that are optional in the type in the type union even though my types say those are present in the result using the `Required` utility type.

Why doesn't the type resolution logic in TypeScript surface these optional-turned-required fields in the result object?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhAIAEBcE8AcCmATRAzcBvT45IFzgDkAhkQNzgD280AllQHYkA2AcgK4C2ARogE4B+Qo259+lAL6TwAQQCyiAM5KSAc0TgQwAFCgIMBCnRYceRISI8K1Wg2YsAytH51Ga4eCUu3aqTIAhRRV1TW09MChzVAxMBWVVDXAAH3AghNCZYMSw3QiQHS0oxC54FhJoTUxszPAAFUKDeBJ+Ei4sOpkuDI1GqH5EaA5+RiUsAAV+Ki46JUQAHgAlRABHDjoB5Hm6gD4dyUbdEiVYRgBjcDQOc-omcEQADzOACxJ3RBqNAApukI0ASiwhXAAyGI3AjEQAHdwJNprNEF8vgMlFQWAA3RAAGhBiAAVogztBAQBeHZYcCgcCAMgItMBwJJ-uQdAc9PSAAa-HLs8Ak8Ds5ZrDYoeZmIyEABEJAlUh2POeAk0XwAkoxKiwWAjRpo7s8qJj+P8dGcmN5wFzQrzwCQoSQ6NB7k9Xu9PoixQRiGQGUydGz6gB5AAi-sIAHVnrBwLNcM9o4wqA6SGczgk6DwWIhBDoLRoAHQ0W4OTi8ATMnSPeBUfgOzCSchAA)
with TSConfig setting switched to JavaScript.

The same problem can be demonstrated in TypeScript: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

**A** solution appears to be to pass in the object explicitly typed as one of the types in the type union. However, I don't understand why TypeScript cannot infer this type implicitly as there is enough information to single out the only possible concrete type the argument and the return value could be.

Comment: You'll need to narrow down your union get the optional field.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler that doesn't appear to be the whole issue as when I hover over `message` it correctly infers that `message` is the shape of `AMessage`, just without the optional-turned-required field. It doesn't think `message` is `Message`.

Comment: Your `const message = await exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' });` is at fault with the return type being `Required<{
    type: "a";
}>`

Comment: Yes, but why is its return type `Required<{ type: "a"; }>` and not `Required<AMessage>`? My expectation is that the `@template` directive should make the generic function monomorphize to the resolved type union type I passed in - `AMessage`.

Comment: Please see my edit, you'll need to define your generic more precisly with an `extend`

Comment: But that just reduces the return type to Message, it is the same as if I never made the function generic, isn't that the case? My aim is for the function to remain generic but return the same member type from the Message union that is passed into it.

Comment: The compiler has no way to know that you passed a `AMessage` as input here. You'll need to move to real TS for that.

Comment: Not even when that's the only possible type it could be since the `type` field on the type union members is the discriminator and its value is present in the argument passed to the function?

Comment: Please look at the difference with a TS code. The Compiler need help with the inference.

Comment: Initially I thought this was specifically a TypeScript + JSDoc question but since I was able to reproduce this in plain TypeScript I asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72922647/2715716. I will update the question if the answer applies here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution based on mapped types:

```js
/** @typedef {{ type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; }} AMessage */
/** @typedef {{ type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; }} BMessage */
/** @typedef {{ a: AMessage; b: BMessage; }} Messages */
/** @typedef {Messages[keyof Messages]} Message */

/**
 * @template {Message} T
 * @param {T} message
 * @returns {Promise<Required<Messages[T["type"]]>>}
 */
async function exchangeMessage(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* … */ });
}

const message = await exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' });
message.optionalNumber; // OK and not optional!
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhAIAEBcE8AcCmATRAzcBvT45IFzgDkAhkQNzgD280AllQHYkA2AcgK4C2ARogE4B+Qo259+lAL6TwAQQCyiAM5KSAc0TgQwAFCgIMBCnRYceRISI8K1Wg2YsAytH51Ga4eCUu3aqTIAhRRV1TW09MChzVAxscBJCBWVVDUoeQiDk0P9wYJTlLV19KKMYrDzQpQBtAGtEWCoMCo0lAF0ZZrDdCJAdLSjELngWEmhNTE6ZABU+g3gSfhIuLCmZLiyNWah+RGgOfkYlLAAFfiouOiVEAB4AJUQARw46HeRrzuqpqoAic2-W1oAPkBklmuhISlgjAAxuA0BwYfQmOBEAAPaEACxI7kQnQAFOsQhoAJRYPrgHZ7A7gRiIADu4FO50uiDxeJ2SioLAAbogADQUxAAK0Q0OgpIAvICsOBQOBAGQEhXAkmJ5B0oJ00KY3nAhPy4Al8TpJDo0BR6KxOPxZiMljIytVOj1oQAdDQkQ5OLwBJRgMBwAB5ADS8UYyBpVDN7vsrAAhDodGj4FR+GbMJJyEA)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a specification on your generic & narrowing then :

```
/** @typedef {{ type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; }} AMessage */
/** @typedef {{ type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; }} BMessage */
/** @typedef {AMessage | BMessage} Message */

/**
 * @template {Message} T extends Message
 * @param {Message} message
 * @returns {Promise<Required<T>>}
 */
async function exchangeMessage(message) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* … */ });
}

const message = await exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' });

if (message.type === 'a') {
  message.optionalNumber; // AMessage
} else {
  message.optionalString; // BMessage
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?filetype=js#code/PQKhAIAEBcE8AcCmATRAzcBvT45IFzgDkAhkQNzgD280AllQHYkA2AcgK4C2ARogE4B+Qo259+lAL6TwAQQCyiAM5KSAc0TgQwAFCgIMBCnRYceRISI8K1Wg2YsAytH51Ga4eCUu3aqTIAhRRV1TW09MChzVAxMBWVVDXAAH3AghNCZYMSw3QiQHS0oxC54FhJoTUxszPAAFXBEAA9KxmQlcBqNQoN4En4SLiwuxBkuDO6iyH5EaA5+Rg7MAAV+Ki46JUQAHgAlRABHDjoZ5G26gD4LyR7dEiVYRgBjcDQOZ-omRqangAsSdyIEYACnGIQ0AEosIVwDM5gtwIxEAB3cCrdabRDA4EzJRUFgAN0QABpYYgAFaIJ7QKEAXguWHAoHAgDICLTAcCSCHkHQ3HRPJjecBgnLgWngEjIkh0aDfP4AjQgsxGSxkTncnQ6OgYUETRAAOnMYtp4tIRChmBhItC+ponwcnF4AkowA58XBiF5jRYW2h4GFettdiYrGcrncLo56Q9vKAA)

---

You'll not have that probleme with TS :

```
type AMessage = { type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; }
type BMessage = { type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; }
type Message = AMessage | BMessage;


async function exchangeMessage<T extends Message>(message: T): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* … */ });
}

const aMessage: AMessage = { type: 'a' };
const message = await exchangeMessage(aMessage);

message.optionalNumber; // Everything is fine

const aMessage2 = { type: 'a' } as const; // as const required 
const message2 = await exchangeMessage(aMessage2); // typed a  { readonly type: "a"; }

message.optionalNumber;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggshAzoghgc2gXigbyqSALigHIUSBuKAezGAEtqA7FAGwDkBXAWwCMIATgH5iTHvwFUAvgCgC0AEIJk6LLnzgIxEr0o06jFqwDKwAfSZoRURGYtppczVGWoMUbPCRvoAHyhK3qoUMqEoiCBMAMZQAGac0QzMUBAAHlEAFiiWEK6qADwAKimpwBBMACaILkEYAHwAFNy1WlCFAJTEAAoC1Nz0iBBFdbgyUFACEMCcAkxQTBAA7lA9fQMQDQ2TiNSsAG4QADQTEABWEFHA7R4jeAD0AFRQgGQEUA93UFLtIbIyUcy2KAoPIYYheFTubB4eTacifEL-JiA5oQtQoRYoejAEqZbIYEEbYEtb6hFE+AB0tCSRi4fEEVDuHwAogcBCBgBl7FABnELBBQojAUTUQAmDzqGGkOFSIHVQXABkfcJQeUnACOnHokwqUD+AOxZNUYuw6Mx2LSuJyBIawp8Iu+UEZGkgOpQ4zwkxQFWYrBAztaACIUAHHDJDRhKQZmGxaRIQjI0mBqAJsXgpBQgA)

Comment: Please switch your TypeScript Playground TSConfig settings to the JavaScript language and retry this. It doesn't work, but I cannot attach the Playground URL in the comment as it is too long.

Comment: I added my TS Playground link to the question.

Comment: Your TypeScript code is not equivalent, it doesn't use a type union (and thus the discrimination by type won't work, you could pass in `"type": "c"`) and the `if` I believe is redudant because when you pass in the argument typed explicitly, then the return value is correct. So while this hinted at one possible solution - type the argument explicitly, it is not IMO a full answer. I have edited my question to include a Playground link to the TypeScript version showing the problem.