# Why cannot a generic TypeScript function with an argument of type from a type union infer the same type as the return type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

```js
type AMessage = { type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; };
type BMessage = { type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; };
type Message = AMessage | BMessage;

function exchangeMessage<T extends Message>(message: T): Required<T> {
  return null as any;
}

const message1 = exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' });

// `optionalNumber` is not accessible, `Required<{ type: "a"; }>` is inferred
message1.optionalNumber;

const message2 = exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' } as AMessage);
message2.optionalNumber;

export {};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggshAzoghgc2gXigbyqSALigHIUSBuKAezGAEtqA7FAGwDkBXAWwCMIATgH5iTHvwFUAvhQBQBaACEEydFlz5wEYiV6UadRi1YBlYAPpM0IqInOW00uQqgrUGKNnhJ30AD5Qyj5qcrIAZpxMAMYMzFAQAB5RABYoVhBuagA8ACrxCcAQTAAmiK7BGAB8ABTcFdpQOQCUxABKEACOnPQCEMW5lbiyUFC9wJwCTFBirKxQKGVpIHJSsrJRzHZQdaoYAIye+SlpGJkY1XgKOuRQUk2hAPQPUAAGtLHGXHyCL1D0ZUxqMB5lEoj56LxWBAADSvdpdHp9LKXLTEABEKDR0kqv3+fyYYUEvWKsh2vj2ADp3kY2F8JKENkwtmS1AAmQ6JY7pM4QC6aIikG5SeZlby7CD3Un1VlUwzMWniQShRJgagCYE4GRAA)

In this code, why must the argument be typed explicitly (as shown in the `message2` line) in order for the return value to be the `AMessage` concrete type and why is `Required<AMessage>` not inferred (`Required<{ type: "a"; }>` is) as the only possible type the return value implicitly when the explicit type cast is not used (as shown in the `message1` line)?

And how can I change this code so the generic function returns either of the union type member types depending on with which of those types the argument type is compatible?

Comment: Would a conditional return type match your need, cf my  edit ?

Comment: Unfortunately I used a simplified example, in my code, I have dozens of messages where the function takes the message object with only the required fields and returns the same object with all fields (required + optional) set and I am looking for a signature that can encode that.

Comment: @​TomášHübelbauer - Both a conditional return type and function overloads can do that. If you used a conditional return type per @MatthieuRiegler's answer, you might define it alongside `Message` to make it easier to keep them in sync. (That might give that solution an edge over the function overloads solution, but it's a judgement call either way. I could see the counter-argument that having to edit the overloads reminds you make sure the implementation handles the new message type. I don't know which I'd pick.)

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I am looking for a signature that can encode the relationship "takes union member type and returns the same type but Required" without actually writing this out for all the member types. and having to keep that in sync. I was sure this would be possible since TypeScript can even do combinations on constant strings slices and crazy advanced stuff like that these days and I was sure this was basic enough to be supported, but it looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to come up with a solution using mapped types:

```js
type AMessage = { type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; };
type BMessage = { type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; };
type Messages = {
  a: AMessage
  b: BMessage
};

type Message = Messages[keyof Messages];

function exchangeMessage<T extends Message>(message: T): Required<Messages[T["type"]]> {
  return null as any;
}

const message = exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' });
message.optionalNumber;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggshAzoghgc2gXigbyqSALigHIUSBuKAezGAEtqA7FAGwDkBXAWwCMIATgH5iTHvwFUAvhQBQBaACEEydFlz5wEYiV6UadRi1YBlYAPpM0IqInOW00uQqgrUGRFGw5ZUKCmJ4JHcIXyheYmVgtVkZWXktV2iMLyTVDwBtAGsIEGoAMzSQxABdOVl8ziYAYwZmKAgAD2qACxQrCDc1AB4AFQbG4AgmABNPLowAPgAKbmTtKF6ASmIAJQgAR056AQgR7omkDN6MgCIFU5KSydww3eBOASYoMVZWf092kDkpeOrmOxQObpdRNVrtDCHaZ4BQ6chQKRLOTAkIAOlodWMXD4gnKTTA1AEwFwMiAA)

The duplication of `type` in the individual messages and the `Message` type union can be solved:

```js
type Messages = {
  a: { requiredNumber: number; optionalNumber?: number; }
  b: { requiredString: number; optionalString?: string; }
};

type MessagesWithTypes = { [type in keyof Messages]: { type: type } & Messages[type] };
type Message = MessagesWithTypes[keyof MessagesWithTypes];

function exchangeMessage<T extends Message>(message: T): Required<Messages[T["type"]]> {
  return null as any;
}

const message = exchangeMessage({ type: 'a', requiredNumber: 0 });
message.requiredNumber;
message.optionalNumber;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzBUC8UDeAoKUSAXDlAE4QCOArgJYUAmActQLYBGEZJAdm52QDcUAPZhgtETyQAbFhy4B+Xvy7CAvvijsS2clTqMAysDK0eKFQqGjxk6TJNmLyqPFPmUG3OsG5coJCwCMho8ADqtMAAFgAq4OhYegDagdDmUADWECAiAGbBiKgIALq6UGkkaVDqUABkhaEIqQklNX7VcEVomI3FEVFxCfDJ2bkFXU0DMfGQ8CV+uHnUPADGElJQEAAeq9FIFhCTxQA8sVvbwBA8DPB9aAB8ABSsIcUksQCUJABKBvQQBgnY5hZKxZIAIjSEJKJQeOC0FGA1DIPCgfBkMkIdwOID8mlwqyk7igr260CwOz2BzQIIgTz0lSgAHIkMyADT6GgA5iqbhQAAMNU+fjJTQAdBRuYx5AJRW80OKxBsHLK1P4dmARGRgDhfEA)

It checks all the boxes: I do not have to specify the input message type explicitly, it is inferred to be one of the types in the type union an the output type is pulled from the mapped type and made `Required`.

I believe this is a "third side" of the conditional return type / function overloads coin. All of these solutions require some sort of maintenance when adding a new message type, but I like this option best as the amount of maintenance is the smallest (one line to the mapped type - do not need to touch the function).

Initially I tried to find a way to derive the mapped type from the type union, something like so:

```js
type Messages = { [type: typeof Message["type"]]: Message[type] }
```

But I don't think that is possible. It eventually lead me onto mapped types and the realization that I can derive the union from the mapped type as well, if I can't have it the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

It's an inference problem. `message` can be of any type that is conforming to `{type: string}`. The compiler has no way to infer that to ONLY `AMessage`.

See this example to understand.

```
type AMessage = { type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; }
type BMessage = { type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; }
type Message = AMessage | BMessage;


async function exchangeMessage<T extends Message>(message: T): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* … */ });
}

const aMessage: AMessage = { type: 'a' };
const message = await exchangeMessage(aMessage);

message.optionalNumber; // Everything is fine

const aMessage2 = { type: 'a' } as const; // as const required to accepted as paramter 
const message2 = await exchangeMessage(aMessage2); // typed a  { readonly type: "a"; }

message2.optionalNumber; // problem
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggshAzoghgc2gXigbyqSALigHIUSBuKAezGAEtqA7FAGwDkBXAWwCMIATgH5iTHvwFUAvgCgC0AEIJk6LLnzgIxEr0o06jFqwDKwAfSZoRURGYtppczVGWoMUbPCRvoAHyhK3qoUMqEoiCBMAMZQAGac0QzMUBAAHlEAFiiWEK6qADwAKimpwBBMACaILkEYAHwAFNy1WlCFAJTEAAoC1Nz0iBBFdbgyUFACEMCcAkxQTBAA7lA9fQMQDQ2TiNSsAG4QADQTEABWEFHA7R4jeAD0AFRQgGQEUA93UFLtIbIyUcy2KAoPIYYheFTubB4eTacifEL-JiA5oQtQoRYoejAEqZbIYEEbYEtb6hFE%20AB0tCSRi4fEEVDuHwAogcBCBgBl7FABnELBBQojAUTUQAmDzqGGkOFSIHVQXABkfcJQeUnACOnHokwqUD%20AOxZNUYuw6Mx2LSuJyBIawp8Iu%20UEZGkgOpQ4zwkxQFWYrBAztaACIUAHHDJDRgRZSDMw2LSJIqoGBerxWBBuKEgA)

---

Edit
Would a conditional return type match your needs ?

```
type AMessage = { type: 'a'; optionalNumber?: number; };
type BMessage = { type: 'b'; optionalString?: string; };
type Message = AMessage | BMessage;

declare function exchangeMessage<T extends Message>(message: T): Required<T extends AMessage ? AMessage :  BMessage>

const aMessage = exchangeMessage({ type: 'a' });
const bMessage = exchangeMessage({ type: 'b' }); 
const cMessage = exchangeMessage({ type: 'c' }); // NOPE 

aMessage.optionalNumber; // OK 
bMessage.optionalString; // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggshAzoghgc2gXigbyqSALigHIUSBuKAezGAEtqA7FAGwDkBXAWwCMIATgH5iTHvwFUAvhQBQBaACEEydFlz5wEYiV6UadRi1YBlYAPpM0IqInOW00uQqgrUGKNnhJ30AD5Qyj5qcrIAJhAAxqwoAtAAZpxMkQzMUBAAHpEAFihWEG5qADwAKukZwBBMYYiuwRgAfAAU3PXaUCUAlMQAShAAjpz0cWGl5ZXVtd6qHkKwhR7EgQsQDbKykcx2UCgrnuU5eRgrTXgKOuRQUp1ym0zbvHvYmYf5J2daOnpXN1AbW8AoJEngdcm82qdNERSJESD8qAB6BFQdgAeQACgBRP6yXZtAB0tFSxi4fEEiORqIA0n9HgSiUY2GYLFYKVBqbIgA)

Comment: *"The compiler has no way to infer that to ONLY `AMessage`."* I think the question is: Why not? It's been told `extends Message`, and the only `Message` that matches `type: a` is `AMessage`. The "why" question remains.

Comment: I don't believe it can be any { type: string }, there is a constraint stemming from the type discriminator, so it can be any object with type of either "a" or "b" but you have showed that extra fields can be added onto the object which I did not expect. Can you explain why that is possible since such an object no longer matches either of the types in the type union which T extends?

Comment: I think if you edit the information from your deleted comment into the question, emphasizing that `extends Message` just means the thing has to be assignment-compatible, that would answer the "why." E.g., it's about assignment-compatibility, not picking between options. Structural typing for the win. :-)

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer - `{type: "a", whatever: 42}` is assignment-compatible with `Message` because it's assignment-compatible with `AMessage`. Extra properties are fine (other than in object literals, as a special case to help us avoid common errors), because that just means it's a subtype. You can assign a subtype to a supertype variable/param/etc.

Comment: I see. I extended the question to ask how can I make the function return either of the member types of the type union even if that would mean losing access to the fields not specified in the member types of the type union.

Comment: I found an answer based on mapped types which I ended up using, feel free to check it out if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

> ...why must the argument be typed explicitly...

Because `T extends Message` just means that `T` has to be assignment-compatible with `Message`, **not** that it has to be (specifically) `AMessage` or `BMessage`. The type `{type: "a"}` is assignment-compatible with `Message` because it's assignment-compatible with `AMessage`. That doesn't mean it **is** an `AMessage`, just that it's compatible with it.

> And how can I change this code so the generic function returns either of the union type member types depending on with which of those types the argument type is compatible?

You can do that using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#overloaded-functions) rather than generics *(or, alternatively, a conditional return type as [Matthieu Riegler points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72922686/157247))*:

```
function exchangeMessage(message: AMessage): Required<AMessage>;
function exchangeMessage(message: BMessage): Required<BMessage>;
function exchangeMessage(message: Message): Required<Message> {
    // ...implementation...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggshAzoghgc2gXigbyqSALigHIUSBuKAezGAEtqA7FAGwDkBXAWwCMIATgH5iTHvwFUAvhQBQBaACEEydFlz5wEYiV6UadRi1YBlYAPpM0IqInOW00uQqgrUGKNnhJ30AD5Qyj5qcrIAZpxMAMYMzFAQAB5RABYoVhBuagAU3MEYxN6qGACUxABKEACOnPQCEAAmADyFvgB8chHRsUzxSanpmRg5edqBgxClUBXVtQ2NQUUQ7eGRMUa9KWkY48OLxOOT0zV1TeOtuLJQV1B1wJwCPWKsrFAoiK9MIHJSsrJRzHYoLlFgBGTwbfrbEZZPAKHTkKBSYqhAD0KKgAANaN02Fw+IIMVB6O8mNRgK8olEfPReKwIAAaTFHWZNWFaYgAIhQHOkrUJxKJTDCghOsmBvhBADpsUZceJBKF-kxAeK1AAmcGJTYDaFsoikBFSV7vFpqZFikZq6WGZhy-GSX6JMDUATknAyIA)

Not using a generic means you're limiting what the function accepts more strictly. The downside is that if you add a third message type, you have to add a third overload (or edit your conditional return type, if using that solution).

Comment: Oof, I did not mention this in my question, but I am using dozens of message types in my code, I was really hoping there would be a utility type or a combination of generics and union type that could encode this.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer - :-) I'm not saying there isn't. I haven't seen one and I *suspect* you'll have to list things out one way or another, but my TypeScript is only "pretty good."

Comment: I found an answer based on mapped types which I ended up using, feel free to check it out if you're interested.